# Meteor blaze template access object property by key without helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I wonder if it is possible to achieve object access by property-string like

```
const obj = { foo:"bar" }
obj["foo"] // returns "bar"
```

via Blaze Spacebars (thus, without using a helper function).

I tried something like

```
{{#with obj}}
  {{this['foo']}}
{{/with}}
```

but it seems that it does not accept the squared brackets. Note: I can not just only type

```
{{this.foo}}
```

because the property name is dynamically given by another object as a value.

Comment: Not possible without a helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a helper function that returns the keys and another that takes in the object and key and returns the value?

```
// JS
Template.registerHelper('keys', function keys (object) {
  return Object.keys(object);
});
Template.registerHelper('pick', function pick (key, object) {
  return object[key];
});

// html
<template name="foo">
  {{#each key in (keys obj)}}
    {{key}} - {{pick key obj}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

---

**EDIT: Just noticed your headline says pretty explicitly "Without helper". I don't think this is possible without a helper**

Comment: I also think global helper is the best way to achive such a thing

Comment: Yeah I used the global helpers in my example for that reason! Very re-suable functions

Comment: I accept it as the best answer, since there is really no way to do this, despite the one you described.